# separating large txt file in pandas data frame or numpy

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am trying to split large .txt file on column
I tried
Using numpy cutoff my data to scientific notation
"
df = np.loadtxt('data1.txt']
dy = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['X_Y', 'X','Y', 'time','weight'])
"
I tried converting the numpy array into dataframe as well but didn't worked

"

- A           B           C           D               E
- 0    6.751537323 260556.2188 5.107021332 1640995201.0    1.0
- 1    4.755306244 260556.2188 5.101299286 1640995202.0    2.0
- 2    6.725025177 260556.2188 5.110740662 1640995204.0    1.0
- 3    6.008720398 260556.2188 5.105113983 1640995205.0    1.0
- 4    6.849765778 260556.2188 5.105304718 1640995206.0    2.0
- 5    6.798267365 260556.2188 5.10225296  1640995208.0    1.0
- 6    4.688739777 260556.2188 5.112838745 1640995209.0    1.0

"

Comment: If you can provide a sample of your input file (e.g. the first 5 lines), it might be possible to help.

Comment: Sorry, data are not presented well but the the data "1640995201" automatically convert to the notation which I wanted to avoid.

Comment: The data's full precision is being retained in memory, but if you don't like the way pandas is printing it, try `pd.set_option('display.precision', 15)`.  [See docs here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/options.html#frequently-used-options)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved my issue

```
df = pd.read_csv("filename.txt", sep = " ",  columns = ['A','B','C','D'])
```

Thank You so much